# How to configure 3rd Party CA in Hyperledger Fabric Test Network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have successfully installed a **Fabric 2.0** `test-network` and I would like to use a 3rd party CA for user verification. So here are the steps that I have done:

```
./network.sh up createChannel -ca
./network.sh deployCC
```

The commands above have successfully created a `test-network`.

Then I copied both of my 3rd party Root CA and Intermediate CA Cert into the MSP folder of `peer0.org1.example.com`. The MSP folder now looks like this:

```
~/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.org/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp
|
|- cacerts
|  |- localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
|  |- RootCA.pem
|- intermediatecerts
|  |- IntermediateCA.pem
|...
|..
|.
```

Then I modified the CA Certificate for Client OU in the `config.yaml`:

```
ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: intermediatecerts/IntermediateCA.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
```

Once done, I restarted the peer by running this command:

```
docker restart peer0.org1.example.com
```

The restart was successful. However, when I tried to invoke the chaincode using a certificate issued by the 3rd Party Intermediate CA, the peer returned this error:

```
[endorser] Validate -> WARN 02a access denied: channel the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority channel=mychannel txID=ca408ba9
```

The certificate has an `OU=client` which I think should be alright. Is there anything else I should do to fix this issue?

*P/S: When I tried to invoke the chaincode using a certificate issued by the Fabric-CA, it works like a charm although the `config.yaml` has been modified.*

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The genesis block of the channel contains MSP information. 
If the MSP has changed, it must be updated to the channel.

There are two ways.

- before create channel, you should change crypto-config files
- after create channel, using [configtxlator](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/configtxlator.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. it at least gives me the idea on the approach i should consider.